# Error: Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Number)

Tags: formula

I wanted to have a formula field with difference between a datefield and todays date.
The formula field is a number to store the no of days.

The formula that i have is

```
TODAY() - SDate__c
```

SDate__c is a Date field.

But when i check syntax it results in

> Error: Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Number).

What am i doing wrong here? OR

How do i get the date difference between todays date and sdate?

Comment: Try with NOW()-Sdate__c

Comment: I believe difference should be of return type number only.SO just try with NOW()-Sdate__c

Comment: @MohithKumar This doesnt work.. the only difference is that error message refers to Datetime instead of Date

Comment: I am kind of surprised since in my org i have difference of two dates and return type i have no and it displays me the duration in no of days

Comment: I am not sure why... Today()-LastactivityDate  works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT :

My bad, it does actually let me create a formula field if both fields are of type date, so `TODAY() - Date_Field__c` in a Number formula field seems to compile okay. Check that your date field is not actually DateTime ? And that your Formula field is of type number.

---

I don't believe you can use mathematical operators on date fields.

You will need to write something like

```
365*(Year(today()) - year(sdate__c)) + 30*(month(today() - month(sdate__c))) + (day(today())- day(sdate__c))
```

Comment: this worked, there was a ')' missing after 30*(month(today(). Strangely Today()-LastactivityDate works.

Answer (score 2):

Can you go back and check your field definitions - is sDate__c definitely a date and your formula is definitely a number formula?
[image: Field definitions]

I defined a couple of fields and I was able to use the formula as you would expect TODAY() - initial_date__c
[image]

Otherwise surely you are in a world of trouble re-inventing the wheel trying to cope with leap years and month lengths?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I was trying to subtract two dates into a date formula field. Just needed to change it to number.

Posting in case that saves anyone some small headache.

Comment: date - date = number, and date +/- number = date